# How to output dates from an array in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, nsdate

Im making a simple planner app which sends notifications to users at specific times that events occur.

I have set up a table to store the data and I am storing individual values inside of an array.

I am encountering a problem outputting the NSDates that I have stored inside of my array.

```
import UIKit


extension NSDate {

convenience init(dateString:String, format:String="h-mm a") {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    formatter.dateFormat = format
    let d = formatter.dateFromString(dateString)
    self.init(timeInterval:0, sinceDate:d!)
}

class MedicineTableViewController: UITableViewController {

//MARK Properties

var medicines = [Medicine]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadSampleMedicine()
 }

 func loadSampleMedicine() {

    let medicine1 = Medicine(name: "Inhaler", time1: NSDate(dateString: "08:00 a"), time2: NSDate(dateString: "10:00 a"), time3: NSDate(dateString: "02:00 p"), time4: NSDate(dateString: "06:00 p"), time5: NSDate(dateString: "10:00 p"))
    medicines.append(medicine1!)
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return medicines.count

}




override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "MedicineTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MedicineTableViewCell
    let medicine = medicines[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel.text = medicine.name
    cell.takeAt.text = "Take At:"
    cell.time1Label.text = medicine.time1
    cell.time2Label.text = medicine.time2
    cell.time3Label.text = medicine.time3
    cell.time4Label.text = medicine.time4
    cell.time5Label.text = medicine.time5


    return cell
}
```

This returns the error "Cannot assign a value of 'NSDate' to a value of type String?"

Is there a way to convert these NSDates into strings?

I have come up with some other possible solution but it involves reworking the whole application so I'd prefer to avoid them if possible.

My possible solution is to rework the data that the user inputs to be a pickerView which has 3 columns one cycling the numbers 01 through to 12, the second 00 to 59 and the third am and pm. and then take the overall string produced and store it in the array. This would allow me to easily print it out since it is just a stored string. Then when I come to the stage at which I am making the notification system I could use the "dateString" function to convert from strings to dates and then program my notifications from that.

So overall I would like to know if I'm able to just print out the NSDates stored in my array or if not if my possible solution would work?

Thanks.

Comment: *"Is there a way to convert these NSDates into strings?"*  – Yes, it is called NSDateFormatter, which has its own tag here: [tag:nsdateformatter]. The is also [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) from Apple.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSDateFormatter`. There is a function called `stringFromDate`. Here is an example.

```
var date = NSDate() //Or whatever your date is

var stringDate = NSDateFormatter().stringFromDate(date)
```